# VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to execute a VB script to copy paste the file and rename with current time system is showing error.

Error - Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

```
ExecuteInsert
Sub ExecuteInsert()
    Const DestinationFolder = "D:\Temp\Help\"
    Const SourceFolder = "D:\Temp\"
    Const SourceFile = "DataFile.xlsx"
    dim DestinationFile as String
    DestinationFile = "DataFile_" & Format(Now, "dd_mm_yyyy hh_mm") & ".xlsx"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.CopyFile SourceFolder & SourceFile, DestinationFolder, True
    Name DestinationFolder & SourceFile As DestinationFolder & DestinationFile
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

VBScript does not support typed dims, all variables are consired equal: Variants. So:

```
    dim DestinationFile as String
==>
    dim DestinationFile
```

The line

```
Name DestinationFolder & SourceFile As DestinationFolder & DestinationFile
```

is not valid VBScript either; I have no clue how to correct it, because I don't know what you want to acheive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply
I want to rename the copied file to filename+ddmmyyyy